# SQL Logic Help - return specific values but excluding values from multiple columns containing same type of data

Tags: sql, logic, informix

I have a table that has the following columns:

MyTable

```
ID| C1 | C2 | C2 |
------------------
1 | 111| 333| 111|
2 | 222| 333| 222|
3 | 333| 333| 444|
4 | 444| 111| 222|
5 | 555| 111| 444|
6 | 111| 222| 111|
7 | 333| 555| 333|
8 | 555| 555| 222|
9 | 222| 111| 555|
10| 444| 111| 222|
11| 777| 888| 999|
```

I want to display the records that contain the values 111, 222 & 444 in columns C1, C2 & C3, but I do not want the records displayed if any of these columns contain the following values: 333, 555.

So my result set should be:

```
4 | 444| 111| 222| 
6 | 111| 222| 111| 
10| 444| 111| 222|
```

I have been racking my brain out trying to get this result set and it is not working for my.  I am using Informix v12.

I tried these but they do not work and are incorrect:

```
select ID, C1, C2, C3
from MyTable
where (C1 in (111, 222, 444) 
       OR C2 in (111, 222, 444) 
       OR C3 in (111, 222, 444)
       )
AND (C1 NOT IN (333, 555) 
     OR C2 NOT IN (333, 555) 
     OR C3 NOT IN (333, 555)
    )
```

and

```
select ID, C1, C2, C3
    from MyTable
    where (C1 in (111, 222, 444) 
           OR C2 in (111, 222, 444) 
           OR C3 in (111, 222, 444)
           )
    AND (C1 NOT IN (333, 555) 
         AND C2 NOT IN (333, 555) 
         AND C3 NOT IN (333, 555)
        )
```

I'm not new at all to SQL but my brain does not seem to be working today.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

> **EDIT**   Added extra row in MyTable to include a record that doesn't include any of the values specified and included another example of what I had tried.

Comment: Inside your AND clause, change all ORs with ANDs

Comment: I have tried this and still did not give me the results I am looking for.

Comment: Post your code. Also, I noticed you use ambersands (&) in your where clause, there need to be only commas (111, 222, 444)

Comment: Ampersand was a copy paste mistake.  Fixed it.

Comment: Try my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Your second query looks fine. (One pair of parentheses is superfluous, though.) What's the problem with it?

Comment: There is no sample record with only one or two columns matching, but I understand that 12|111|888|999 would be included in your results, as a column matches 111/222/444 and no column matches 333/555.

Answer (score 2):

You got confused with `AND` and `OR` and had `&` instead of a comma.

```
select *
from mytable
where
(
     c1 in (111, 222, 444) 
  or c2 in (111, 222, 444) 
  or c3 in (111, 222, 444)
)
and c1 not in (333, 555) 
and c2 not in (333, 555) 
and c3 not in (333, 555);
```

or:

```
select *
from mytable
where
(
     c1 in (111, 222, 444) 
  or c2 in (111, 222, 444) 
  or c3 in (111, 222, 444)
)
and not
(
     c1 in (333, 555) 
  or c2 in (333, 555) 
  or c3 in (333, 555)
);
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XQVTFM1638

Comment: Trying this now!  Ampersand was a typo :)

Comment: For the record, THIS worked!  Thank-you @ThorstenKettner !

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from cte (collect the valid data here) to eliminate the data you do not want like below:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (
      number INT,
      score1 INT,
      score2 INT,
      score3 INT
    )

INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (1, 111,333,111)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (2, 222,333,222)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (3, 333,333,444)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (4, 444,111,222)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (5, 555,111,444)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (6, 111,222,111)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (7, 333,555,333)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (8, 555,555,222)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (9, 222,111,555)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (10, 444,111,222)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  (11, 777,888,999)

CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLE_TMP (number int) with NO LOG;

INSERT INTO TABLE_TMP
select number
from mytable
where score1 not in (111,222,444)
   or score2 not in (111,222,444)
   or score3 not in (111,222,444)

select *
from mytable m
where not exists (select * from TABLE_TMP t where t.number=m.number)
```

Comment: Thank you @eray  I see what you are doing there.  I have edited my original post to include an extra row that does not contain any of values I am trying to include or omit to better represent my issue.

Comment: I added this row to my sample dataset and run the same query (updated my answer), still working fine for me? not for you? @DB_G

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Unfortunately Informix still does not support CTE's. Other equivalent constructs must be used.

Comment: @LuísMarques thanks for your comment. Can you please check now if my answer works for informix?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli To work in Informix It must be `INSERT INTO TABLE_TMP SELECT number FROM mytable WHERE ...`, but otherwise your answer gives the expected results: rows with column number equal to 4, 6 and 10.

Comment: Corrected my answer as you directed. Thanks!! @LuísMarques